# How to set global array's size after calling a function? (C)

Tags: c

Is it possible to set a global array's size after calling a function? Example: If you are reading some numbers from a file and you want to store those numbers in a global array, but you dont know how many of those numbers there are before you read them from the file, so that the size of the array is unknown.

Comment: Open your C book and check the chapter *dynamic memory allocation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an array can't be resized. So if you have something like

```
int myArray[10];
```

there is nothing you can do to change the size.

What you can do is to use dynamic memory like:

```
int* myArray;

int main(void)
{
    int myArraySize = 10;
    myArray = malloc(myArraySize * sizeof(int));  // Allocate memory for 10 int
    if (myArray == NULL)
    {
        // Out of memory
        return -1;
    }

    // Now you can use myArray just like an ordinary array,
    // like myArray[0] to myArray[9]

    //..... Read from file in a loop
    int numbersRead = 0;
    while (....)
    {
        // Read a number from the file
        number = .....;

        if (numbersRead == myArraySize)
        { 
            // No more space in array

            // Use realloc to allocate 
            // more memory, i.e. so that you change the "array" size

            // Update myArraySize to the new array size
         }
         myArray[numbersRead] = number;
         numbersRead++;
    }

    free(myArray);

    return 0;
}
```

BTW - In general you should avoid global variables

Answer (score 0):

Standard C arrays need to be dimensioned at compile time, so the compiler/linker can allocate space for them.
That obviously excludes *any* run-time sizing.

You can allocate them with `malloc` on the heap of course, and this allows run-time sizing.

Answer (score 0):

You say C, so I expect you use dynamic memory (malloc).

There is one way to allocote memory that will last for sure and then shrink it.
Or you try a small piece and grow it. Resizing of memory is with realloc.

Another strategy is to first calculate the required size.
If you know every number needs 2 bytes in the file then is is pretty easy to get the size of the array if you have the filesize.

That all is for dynamic memory. Static memory (e.g. int a [3]) can not be changed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody seemed to mention variable-length arrays. You could do this:

```
int myarray[getSizeFunction()];
```

This way you are effectively setting the array's size depending on the function call.

Of course that would only be possible if your array is a local variable, if it has to be global then dynamic memory allocation is your only option.